# Multiplicative $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, binary-operations

**Question:** How to prove that $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_p$ is a group under multiplication operation where $p$ is prime.

**Proof:**
We define $$\mathbb{Z}^{*}_p=\{[a] \in \mathbb{Z}_p: [a] \neq [0]\}$$

*1.* For well-defined:
By assumption $[a] \neq [0]$ so $p| a$ thus $(a, p)=1$.

Let $[a], [b] \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}_p$. Then $$[a][b]=[ab]=[0]$$

$$ab \equiv 0\pmod{p}$$

so, $$ p|ab$$ since $(a, p)=1$ and $p|a$. This contradicts to the assumption that $[b] \neq [0]$ thus $[ab] \neq [0]$ therefore $[ab] \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}_p$

2. Associative law
   Let $[a], [b], [c] \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}_p$. Then
   $$[a]([b][c])=([a][b])[c]$$
3. Identity Element
4. Inverse Element

How to check associativity, identity and inverse so that $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_p$ forms a group under multiplication operation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I just don't know how to satisfy remaining axioms.

Comment: (3) We have that $1$ is the multiplicative identity for $\Bbb Z$.  Have you checked if $[1]$ works here?  (4) Have you heard of [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)?

Comment: 2. $$[a]([b][c])=[a][bc]=[a(bc)]=[(ab)c]=[ab][c]=([a][b])[c]$$

Comment: 3. $$[a][1]=[a]=[1][a]$$ $$[a][1]=[a1]=[a]$$ $$[1][a]=[1a]=[a]$$

Comment: 4. Bézout's Identity: for some $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t $$an+bp=1=gcd(n, p).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt for (1) is almost correct in the math part, but is poorly written. I will rewrite what you did in a rigorous way:

By contradiction, let us assume that there exists $[a],[b]\in\mathbb{Z}^*_p$, such that $[a][b]\notin\mathbb{Z}^*_p$. Then $[a][b]=[ab]=[0]$, which implies $ab\equiv 0$ (mod p), so $p\mid ab$. Since $p$ is a prime number, either $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$, which is equivalent to say that $[a]=[0]$ or $[b]=[0]$. Hence, $[a]\notin\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ or $[b]\notin\mathbb{Z}^*_p$, contradiction.

For (2), (3) and (4), the only difficult part is the existence of an inverse (since associative and identity follows from the associative and identity of $\mathbb{Z}$), to do this let $[n]\in\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, WLOG, we can say that $n\in\lbrace 1,\dots,p-1\rbrace$. Since $p$ is prime $\gcd(n,p)=1$. Applying Bezout's identity there is some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $an+bp=\gcd(n,p)=1$. From this we have immediately that $[a]$ is the inverse element of $[n]$.

Comment: I am still confused with part 4. Also check my attempt in part 1. If it is okay, then tell me.

Comment: Since $an+bp=\gcd(n,p)=1$ and we are in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ we know that $[0]=[p]$, so $[an+bp]=[1]$, which implies $[a][n]+[b][p]=[1]$ and so $[a][n]=[1]$. By commutativity of $\mathbb{Z}·$ it follows that $[a][n]=[1]=[n][a]$, and so $[n]^{-1}=[a]$.

Comment: Hope you now understand everything, tell me if you need extra help. Parts (2) and (3) are fairly simple, maybe you can try to do them as an exercise to check you understood the problem.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.